# Set up tengwarscript

Tags: miktex

Could anyone give me a brief explanation of how to install the tengwarscript package? I understand it needs special fonts installed separately, but I don't know where to put them and how... I'm using MikTeX on Windows (yes, blame me).

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format. I don't know `tengwarscript`, but i don't know about others. Do you mind putting some additional information to your question to help people understand the topic even if they are *unexperienced*?

Comment: According to CTAN, this package is included in both, TeX Live and MikTeX, as `tengwarscript`, so i think you can download this using the package mahager of MikTeX.

Comment: Is the question how to install the package? Or is it how to install the fonts? Your question is ambiguous. As @Johannes_B says, the package you can install using MiKTeX's package manager, I think. Then there are the fonts. Which are you using? What format are they in? How are they named? We definitely need more information to be of much help...

Comment: Did you read the README file and the package manual's section on font installation? Although the script included is for bash, it should also be helpful as a basis. You just need to adapt the steps for MiKTeX. (If you were using TeX Live, you would need to adapt them for TeX Live since the script assumes you are using teTeX.)

Comment: the package was installed "on the fly", but the readme says I have to install certain fonts and a "map" myself. The fonts are in .ttf format